# Can a Rails 3 app find some way to handle Backbone.js { patch: true }..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to just update a couple particular attributes with Backbone.js. Looks like Backbone.js offers the `{patch : true }` option, *but* it also seems that Rails 3 doesn't know what to do with the PATCH method..

What kind of workaround can I do without having to upgrade Rails and still accomplish updating  a couple attributes in a PUT request.

Comment: I've overrided backbone's `methodMap` (`'patch':  'PUT'`) and in rails backend handle PUT method as a PATCH (default behavior of rails is ok most of the times). Not a good way at all, but still a way!

Comment: Oooo wow can you explain that in a bit more detail in an Answer? Totes what I'm looking for! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In backbone lines #1188 to 1194 this code handle method mapping :

```
var methodMap = {
  'create': 'POST',
  'update': 'PUT',
  'patch':  'PATCH',
  'delete': 'DELETE',
  'read':   'GET'
};
```

Edit `'patch':  'PATCH',` to `'patch':  'PUT',`.

For version 1.1.0

In version <=1.0.0 there's no need to update backbone.js itself, just override `Backbone.methodMap` add :

```
Backbone.methodMap.patch = 'PUT'
```

<sub>On top of your js files and after load of backbone</sub>

In rails backend, just update model in proper way (`someModel.update_attributes(this_model_params)`

P.S : It's not a good way! But I (in my own use case) hadn't found any code that extends rails to support HTTP PATCH verb.

Comment: Ah awesome, now we're haxxor bros